# Troubles downloading csv files from Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I think i'm failing to understand what i'm doing wrong. I have connected to the Google Drive API and now I would like to read a few documents on my Google drive with the objective of analysing the data contained in these csv files.

This is the code I have:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from httplib2 import Http
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/emmanuelsibanda/credentials.json"
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
  with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
    creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

def gdrive_download(file_id):
  request = service.files().get(fileId=file_id)
  return request.execute()
a = gdrive_download('19sPsANUblhXkb3nZVy4PMrfUyOSoF_uQ')
```

Just to reiterate I would like to download a few csv files  and then proceed to read the files.

Comment: Show your error

Comment: What is not working with the code you have now?

Comment: I guess the confusion on my part is reading the data in the the file. From what I see I only have the file's ID, file name etc but not the actual contents of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drive, a File's metadata is separate from its content. You have asked for `metadata.readonly` scope, which unsurprisingly only allows access to the metadata. Your call to `files().get` then gets the metadata.

To get the content, you will firstly need to choose a more permissive scope. Then you will fetch the content. How you do this depends on whether the file is a binary file, or a Google document (eg. a spreadsheet).

A binary file can be downloaded by adding `alt=media` to the URL.

A Google file can be exported by adding `/export?mimeType=text/csv` to the URL.

See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads for details and code samples.