# Obtain file content using Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to donwload a file i've uploaded to a Team Drive using the v3 method from `drive().files().get()` as described in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).
I can get the metadata, like file ID and permissions, but don't know how to access the actual binary content, e.g. to write it to a file. The file in question is a plain text file.

This is part of the code i'm using.

```py
    request = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, supportsTeamDrives=True)
    pprint.pprint(request.to_json())
    response = request.execute()
    pprint.pprint(response)
```

And the response (from the pprints)
Request

```
{
  "uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1CxxxxxxxxxxxxHp?supportsTeamDrives=true&alt=json", 
  "method": "GET",
  "body": null,
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "user-agent": "google-api-python-client/1.7.8 (gzip)"
  },
  "methodId": "drive.files.get",
  "resumable": null,
  "response_callbacks": [],
  "_in_error_state": false, 
  "body_size": 0,
  "resumable_uri": null, 
  "resumable_progress": 0
}
```

File Metadata

```py
{'id': '1CxxxxxxxxxxxxHp',
 'kind': 'drive#file',
 'mimeType': 'text/plain',
 'name': 'test.txt',
 'teamDriveId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}
```

I can access file metadata, but don't know how to get the file's contents, to write to a file.

I'm using the full access scope, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".

Documentation says "Gets a file's metadata or content by ID.", but it doesn't explain how.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubles downloading csv files from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261031/troubles-downloading-csv-files-from-google-drive)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. After trying different options, i came to a solution mixing info from different posts.

1 - The get_media() method works in v3 but is not documented anywhere (even on v2 docs).
2 - io.BytesIO dindn't work, changed to FileIO.

The result code was something like this:

```py
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.FileIO(filename, "wb")
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
```

Google Api documentation is really messy and inconsistent in so many ways.

Comment: The `get_media` is documented in the Python Client docs for the Drive API btw: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get_media

Comment: Thank you so much, I was banging my head since 3 hours. Just couldn't understand why a simple task like reading a plain text file is not well documented.

Comment: Google drive API docu says about files().get but the example shows files().get_media instead.